# What does a "key-protecting key" mean in encryption?

Tags: sql-server, encryption

In the [MS docs about Always Encrypted columns in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#selecting--deterministic-or-randomized-encryption), it's said that the "column master key is a key-protecting key that encrypts one or more column encryption keys."

What does this mean? The CEK is used to encrypt and decrypt the sensitive information. What does it mean for the CEK to be "protected" by another key?

Answer (score 0):

It means the second key isn't stored in the clear (note, I don't mean to imply the first is either). Before you can even get the column encryption keys, you need to decrypt *them* using the column master key.

That is how the other keys are protected by the first.

Comment: This is done so you can rotate the keys without decrypting and re-encrypting the data.